# Wordpress plugin for adding custom fields to menu

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

Can anyone tell me if there is a Wordpress plugin which allows you to custom fields to the menu.

I've created four custom fields:

Version
Author Name
Year
Group

I would like to be able to show the contents on these fields in a menu.
A click would lead you to the page.

Comment: Are you using wordpress wp-nav_menu

Comment: yes actually thats what to i need. i use wp_nav_menu